# How to exclude matching values from dictionary object in angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, dictionary

I have created a function that takes a dictionary object and matches array as below:

```
const dict = {
  CheckAStatus: "PASS",
  CheckAHeading: "",
  CheckADetail: "",
  CheckBStatus: "FAIL",
  CheckBHeading: "Heading1",
  CheckCStatus: "FAIL",
  CheckCHeading: "Heading2"
};
```

I want to exclude all the key value pairs which have either `PASS` as the value or `empty string ("")` as the value.
In other words, `JSON.stringify(dict)` should give:

```
  CheckBStatus: "FAIL",
  CheckBHeading: "Heading1",
  CheckCStatus: "FAIL",
  CheckCHeading: "Heading2"
```

I have written below but it is not working

```
 const items = Object.keys(dict)
  .filter(key => key.indexOf('PASS')>= 1)
```

Comment: Why angular tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a simple `for...in` loop to add key/value pairs to your `items` object when it meets the right criteria.

```js
const dict = {
  CheckAStatus: "PASS",
  CheckAHeading: "",
  CheckADetail: "",
  CheckBStatus: "FAIL",
  CheckBHeading: "Heading1",
  CheckCStatus: "FAIL",
  CheckCHeading: "Heading2"
};

const items = {};

for (let key in dict) {
  if (!["PASS", ""].includes(dict[key])) {
    items[key] = dict[key];
  }
}

console.log(items);
```